# Receiving vector object not updating properly (networking)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, vector

I am attempting to create a simple users online but cant seem to get the String vector to update properly.

Client Code: (Both vectors are global)

```
else if(command.equals("GET USER LIST")){
        test = (Vector)ois.readObject();

        for(String s: test){
            if(!usersConnected.contains(s)){
                usersConnected.add(s);
                jlConnUsers.setText(jlConnUsers.getText() + s + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Test array " + test);
     System.out.println("User array " + usersConnected);
}
```

Server Code:

```
public void getActiveUserList(){
    for(ClientConnection client: activeConnections){
        String user = client.getUserName();
        if(!activeUserList.contains(user)){
            activeUserList.add(user);
        }
        System.out.println("sent TO client FULL USER LIST:" + activeUserList);
    }
}
```

So, client connects, hits a button "Get user list" which gets sent to the server, server goes through hashmap, adds all current client names to a vector and sends it back...

My issue: If I connect one client and get the user list, it will display the SINGLE name properly. If I connect two clients and attempt to get the user list, client 1 will not receive the updated vector EVEN THOUGH the server is sending the correct vector.

The Server always sends the correct vector with the correct user names.

```
   Client 1: Name 1 (Will not update after more clients connect)
   Client 2: Name 1, Name 2 (Will not update after more clients connect)
   Client 3: Name 1, Name 2, Name 3 (Will not update after more clients connect)
```

If I access the getusers BEFORE another client connects, I can not get the correct vector again.

Im fairly certain im missing something extremely small here, I could be wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `if(!activeUserList.contains(user)){
            activeUserList.add(user);
        }` seems like it should be a Set

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been solved. REFERENCES to the vector were being passed instead of the new vector.

Calling the "reset" method prior to sending over the object seems to have fixed this.